# How to see the indexing rate in elasticsearch cluster in AWS on Kibana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, indexing, kibana, amazon-elasticsearch

If you deploy elasticsearch on a server, you can see the indexing rate on "Stack Monitoring", but this option is missing from Elasticsearch in AWS. Is there any way to activate it or to replicate it with other software?

Comment: I am assuming that you're talking about AWS Managed Elasticsearch. If yes, then the information should be available in the "Cluster Health" tab, as well as from CloudWatch. Do you not see it there?

Comment: Ok, sorry I am quite new to this and I missed that! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: No problem. I know that some information isn't available for an in-VPC deployment.